# angular form pattern validaton for one word or HH:mm

Tags: angular, forms, validation

i try to set a pattern for HH:mm

if his shop is closed he should only able to entry "closed" or the hours if opened.

```
ngModel pattern="[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] && [closed]"
```

but this doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Write the pattern as `pattern="^[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$|^closed$"`

or

`pattern="^[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]$|^closed$"`

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel pattern="^[1-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$"` is your pattern validation.
`&& [closed]` is something else.
Please provide more context so we can help in the next steps

Comment: i mean only the time or "Closed" should be able to be entered in the input field nothing else. I'm developing an app for shop owners.

Comment: the word "closed"?  or you're trying to check afterward some boolean value named close?